# Binding properties of the component created by the Loader

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

I want to load the main window depending on the condition:

```
Loader {
    source: blocky ? "BlockyMainWindow.qml" : "RoundyMainWindow.qml"
}
```

But the properties to bound are the same: `width`/`height`, `anchors`, `transform`.

It works only when all that is written in the `onLoaded` handler. In addition, you have to write it two times: one time to do `Qt.binding` and second time to just assign values because the binding can't kick in without some value changes.

Properties:

```
    width: ContentOrientation.rotated ? parent.height : parent.width
    height: ContentOrientation.rotated ? parent.width : parent.height

    anchors.left: parent.left
    anchors.top: ContentOrientation.rotated ? parent.bottom : parent.top
    transform: Rotation { origin.x: 0; origin.y: 0; angle: ContentOrientation.rotated ? -90 : 0 }
```

How to make it simple?

Comment: Can you show these properties that you're binding that are the same?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can probably move those property bindings to the `Loader` itself:

```
Loader {
    source: blocky ? "BlockyMainWindow.qml" : "RoundyMainWindow.qml"

    width: ContentOrientation.rotated ? parent.height : parent.width
    height: ContentOrientation.rotated ? parent.width : parent.height
    // etc.
}
```

For example:

```
import QtQuick 2.3
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4

Window {
    id: window
    visible: true

    Component {
        id: blockyComponent

        Rectangle {
            color: "red"

            Text {
                text: "Blocky"
            }
        }
    }

    Component {
        id: roundedComponent

        Rectangle {
            color: "green"
            radius: 20

            Text {
                text: "Rounded"
            }
        }
    }

    Loader {
        sourceComponent: loaderType.checked ? blockyComponent : roundedComponent
        anchors.fill: parent
        rotation: 90
    }

    Switch {
        id: loaderType
    }
}
```

See [Loader sizing behavior](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-loader.html#loader-sizing-behavior) for more information.

Comment: What if i want to bind a custom property?